# mysql.proc does not exist on database restore

Tags: mysql, upgrade, database-restore

A couple of months ago I upgraded my Lubuntu from 12.10 to 16.10, seemingly without any problems.

A short while later mysqld crashed while I was trying to create a new database, and wouldn't restart.

After some testing I found that I had to add innodb_force_recovery=2 to the mysql.cnf file to get it up and running.

Mysqlcheck cannot find any errors, so I have dumped all databases to a backup file, and the result looks correct.

Some experimentation has shown the problem probably is located in the file ibdata1, removing this allows mysqld to start and run normally, but a lot of tables naturally doesn't exist.

I understand there are no way to repair the innodb databases, so I have emptied the mysql data directory (I do have a backup), making mysqld rebuild the system databases. But when I try to restore my dump file it creates most of my databases then stops with the error "mysql.proc does not exist".

I'm stuck here, and have been unable to find any clue on how to solve this problem on the net.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been solved, it seems it was necessary to run mysql_upgrade after the initialization and before the restore of the backup.

Comment: `mysql_upgrade -u root -p` solved the issue here too